# Purpose of stateless ACLs in gen2 VPC?

Tags: ibm-cloud

A newbie question on using subnet ACLs with IBM gen2 VPC.

I've an internet facing application which accepts inbound requests, as well as, makes outbound requests to the peer hosts.  To enable this, I've to practically open all(>1024) inbound and outbound ports on my subnets.

I'm using IBM's security groups to firewall my VMs, but just curious why make the ACLs stateless, and force the user to open all ports?  I certainly see the usage of subnet to subnet ACLs but I'm asking about in my particular use case.

Am I missing something here?  Would you please recommend best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Stateless network acls are common for cloud providers supplying VPC.  If the remote IP ranges are not fixed it will not be possible to limit them further with acls.  Same with the ports where in your example most port numbers will be valid except the non-ephemeral ports that you are not using (as you mention).

You can imagine more constrained use cases where acls would add another layer of security and associated reasoning about connectivity.  Say you had a Direct Link from on premises to the cloud and the IP range could be constricted, etc.